# facebook api - list user identificators I invited to an event

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm writting application for facebook using canvas using facebook php api.

My problem: is it possible (and if yes - how) to get from api list of users i (or user who gave me permision using AccessToken) invited to an event?

When i list event_members table using FQL i dont get inviter nor inviter_type informations...

```
SELECT inviter,inviter_type,rsvp_status,uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = someeventid
```

That query ends with those fields empty - and from what i read thats expected behaviour becouse its private date - who invited who.